# vee-validate Validating a non-existing field

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

When validating a group of fields, an error is shown for fields that are hidden in the DOM with a v-if attribute.

For example, I've got 3 fields:

```
<input name="foo" v-validate="'required'" />
<input name="bar" v-validate="'required'" />
<input v-if="showMe" name="foobar" v-validate="'required'" />
```

When I run my submit func I'm checking that none of the fields contain errors:

```
this.$validator.validateAll().then(() => {
  ... my check
});
```

I see the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: [vee-validate] Validating a non-existent field: "#3". Use "attach()" first.
```

Detaching and reattaching my 'foobar' field as I update the "showMe" state seems verbose. Especially for my larger multistep forms.

Is there an easier way to prevent this error from appearing?

Comment: use `v-show` instead of `v-if`?

Comment: If I use v-show then the 'required' validation kicks in and I see an error that I have not completed all mandatory fields

Answer (score 4):

You need to combine `v-show` with dynamically applied validation rules.  This is where you pass the rules as an object, with the first key:value being the rule name and a boolean for if required (which can be the same as the v-if boolean).

## For VeeValidate 2 (old version in question)

```
<input name="foo" v-validate="'required'" /> <br >
<input v-show="showMe" name="bar" v-validate="{required: showMe}" />
```

[See Sandbox Example for VeeValidate2](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-cartwright-x4ltr)

## For VeeValidate 3

```
<validation-provider rules="required">
    <input type="text" v-model="foo">
</validation-provider>

<validation-provider :rules="{required: showMe}">
   <input type="text" v-model="bar" v-show="showMe">
</validation-provider>
```

[See Sandbox Example for VeeValidate 3](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-minsky-kl7er).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a validation on hidden input, you just need to set field's display to none:

```
<input style="display: none">
```

This method works fine for me!